# Akamai purge cache CLI: API Error: 400 400 Bad Request Invalid timestamp More Info https://problems.luna.akamaiapis.net/-/pep-authn/request-error

Tags: ssl, command-line-interface, cdn, akamai, tls1.0

I am trying to figure out how to Purge the Akamai cache through the Akamai CLI (version 1.3.1).
I am using a `~/.edgerc` with :

```
[default]
host = *.luna.akamaiapis.net
client_token = akab-****
client_secret = ****
access_token = akab-****
```

These credentials provide access to the following settings:

- **API service name**: *CCU APIs*
- **Description**: *Content control utility APIs*
- **Access level**: *READ-WRITE*

When I execute the following command in my Mac terminal:

```
akamai purge --section default  invalidate --production --cpcode 381644
```

I get the following error:

```
Purging...... [FAIL]
API Error: 400 400 Bad Request Invalid timestamp More Info https://problems.luna.akamaiapis.net/-/pep-authn/request-error
```

I have tried going to https://problems.luna.akamaiapis.net/-/pep-authn/request-error but that page does not seem to exist anymore. I am not sure what to do to get this working properly. If anyone has recommendations I'd love to hear about them as I do not know how to proceed to troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Nicola

Answer (score 0):

It would nice to try to flush the DNS cache first.

https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/question/0D54R00007EhoqNSAR/akamai-fast-purge-api-giving-invalid-timestamp-despite-efforts-to-synchronize-time?language=en_US